# SQL procedure algorithm generating numbers in HEX (using strings)

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to make an algorithm in SQL (stored procedure) which will generate numbers in a non-decimal number system (we can use HEX here) and write them down into file. The only issue is that, I need to use only strings to do that.
I have declared my set of characters: '0123456789ABCDEF' and now I need to make a loop in witch I generate next element and save it into file.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm using DB2, sorry for no tag.

Comment: `WITH T(I) AS (VALUES 1 UNION ALL SELECT I+1 FROM T WHERE I<10) SELECT HEX(I) FROM T`. This select generates 10 hex strings from 1 to 10 integers. If it's not what you need, then please, provide more details on what you need exactly with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a decimal -> hex conversion?

```
with data (n) as (
values (90)
union  all
select n + 1
from   data
where  n < 100
),
    alphabet (a) as (
values ('0123456789ABCDEF')
),
    dechex (orig,n,hx) as (
select n, n / 16,cast(substr(a,mod(n, 16) + 1, 1) as varchar(10))
from   data
cross  join alphabet
union  all
select orig,n / 16,substr(a,mod(n, 16) + 1, 1) concat hx
from   dechex
cross  join alphabet
where  n > 0
)
select orig,hx
from   dechex 
where  n = 0
order  by orig
```